# Python Numpy adding matrix to original matrix (changing original)

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I want to add a matrix to another matrix using Numpy. I can add two matrices but I can't seem to find a way to add it to the original one. I always get a 'new' matrix with the combination of the two matrices. Is there any way to replace matrix with the sum of the original matrix + another one?

Thanks!

Edit: Code:

```
for i in tqdm(range(len(x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6]))):
  x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6][i] += x_test_da[y_test_orig == 9][0]
```

Comment: please provide actual examples of what you did, how it failed, and what you expected

Comment: You can use the `+=` operator to update arrays in-place

Comment: Hi, i added the code I used. I want to add x_test_da[y_test_orig == 9][0] to x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6][i] but it doesn't seem to add it. I also tried using the numpy.add function, this works but only for a new array, not adding to the original one.

Comment: I tried updating a single value of the array using x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6][I][0,0] but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: The array x_test_orig has 10000 28x28 matrices, i use y_test to select matrices that have the label '6' and '9'

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? I assume that the number of values where `y_test_orig == 9` and `y_test_orig == 6` are not the same shape. To add two arrays together they must have the same number of elements or be able to be broadcasted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your loop isn't writing to `x_test_da`. When you do

```
x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6][i] += ...
```

that's equivalent to

```
temp = x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6]
temp[i] += ...
```

where `temp` is a *new* array not backed by the `x_test_da` array, because `x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6]` is an [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) operation that cannot create a view. You're writing to a new array created by the advanced indexing operation.

Even if your loop meant what you wanted, it would still be extremely inefficient. It's repeating the unnecessary work of evaluating `x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6]` and `x_test_da[y_test_orig == 9]` on every iteration, taking time proportional to `len(y_test_orig)` on every iteration of the loop, and it's performing a Python-level loop to assign values one at a time instead of pushing the work to NumPy.

Drop the loop. Let NumPy handle this:

```
x_test_da[y_test_orig == 6] += x_test_da[y_test_orig == 9][0]
```

You don't get a tqdm progress bar this way, but unlike your original loop, this should be fast enough that you won't *need* a progress bar.

Comment: Great this works! Thank you a lot!